# CRON and Python notices contributing to hanging search results

Tags: python, django, cron, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Long story short, I have a search engine using the following configuration:

- Python 2
- Django
- Selenium
- BeautifulSoup
- A Cloud VPS

I'm scraping information, sorting it, and then displaying the results. However, some of my searches cause the loading page to totally hang and the search results never display (it shouldn't take longer than 60s). Looking into Cron & python notifications, I'm seeing the following:

```
In /var/log/syslog:
[2:28:13 PM] Jan 27 23:25:01 xxxxx CRON[xxxx]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jan 27 23:25:16 xxxxx sd.forwarder[xxxx]: INFO (transaction.py:158): No transaction to flush during flush #120
Jan 27 23:25:55 xxxxx sd.collector[xxxx]: INFO (collector.py:521): Finished run #10. Collection time: 5.13s. Emit time: 0.04s
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Comment: did you check this inforamtion `INFO (transaction.py:158): No transaction to flush during flush`. Log more information and maybe you find problem.

Comment: I tried, but wasn't finding anything. That's why I posted here.